# Closed form of $x_{n+1}=x_n-1/x_n$ with $x \neq 0,1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, closed-form

I have the sequence

$x_{n+1}=x_n-1/x_n$ with $x \neq 0,1$

For certain values of $x_0$ this sequence will be periodic. To find these values one can look at the root of:
$x_{p} = x_0$ where $p$ is the period. For $p=2$ this can be solved easily.

For $p>10$ it's not viable to define the function recursively and search for roots numerically.
To look for the roots at higher values of $p$  I'm searching for a closed form of this formula.

I already found an answer to a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575559/closed-form-of-x-n1-frac12-leftx-n-frac1x-n-right-with-x-0-n), but failed to transfer the solution to my different sequence. I tried using the same approach.

By $x=\cot(\theta)$ you get:
$x_1=2\cot(2\theta)=\cot(\theta)-\frac{1}{\cot(\theta)}$

I calculated $x_2$ by hand which is:
$x_2=\cot(4\theta)+\frac{3}{2}\cot(2\theta)$
But I wasn't able to find a simple formula for $x_3$

Any help with finding a closed form (or an idea how to find the roots more easily) would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** 
I moved my follow up questions to a seperate [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3982226/871291)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equations $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac 1{x_n}$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac 12 \left( x_n - \frac 1{x_n} \right)$ are maybe similar in appearance but very different qualitatively. For instance, the first one has no fixed points while the second one does (in the complex numbers):
$$
x = \frac 12 \left( x - \frac 1x \right) = \frac{x^2-1}{2x} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 2x^2 = x^2 - 1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x^2 + 1 = 0
$$
and so it has the solutions $\pm i$. If the first one had fixed points, it would imply $x = x - \frac 1x$ has a solution, but this clearly has no solution.

Working on our original problem again but considering $x_{n+2}$ as a function of $x_n$ instead, we get
$$
x_{n+2} = x_{n+1} - \frac 1{x_{n+1}} = \frac{x_{n+1}^2 - 1}{x_{n+1}} = \frac{\left(\frac{x_n^2-1}{x_n}\right)^2 - 1}{\frac{x_n^2 -1}{x_n}} = \frac{x_n^4 - 3x_n^2 + 1}{x_n(x_n^2-1)}
$$
and if the recurrence equation $y_n = x_{2n}$ has a fixed point, then it satisfies $y_{n+1} = x_{2n+2} = x_{2n} = y_n$, so we can use the above equation and deduce
$$
-\frac 14 = y^4 - y^2 = y^2(y^2-1) = y^4 - 3y^2 + 1 = \frac 14 - \frac 32 + 1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 2y^2 - 1 = 0
$$
which means $y = \pm \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ are the possible values of $x_0$ for which the sequence $x_{2n}$ will be periodic.

You might wonder, if starting with $x_0 = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ means $x_0 = x_2 = \cdots$, what happens to $x_1,x_3,\cdots$? Well, since $x_{2n+1} = f(x_{2n})$, and $x_{2n} = x_0$ for all $n \ge 0$, it follows that $x_{2n+1} = x_1$ for all $n \ge 0$. This means that if $x$ is a solution to $f(f(x)) = x$, then $f(x)$ is also a solution to $f(f(x)) = x$, and because we know there are no solution to $f(x) = x$, it has to be a distinct one! We deduce the following result:

> Let $p$ be a positive integer. If $x$ is a solution to the equation $f^{(p)}(x) = x$ (where $f^{(p)}(x)$ is obtained by applying $f$ on $x$ precisely $p$ times), then $x, f(x), \cdots, f^{(k)}(x), \cdots, f^{(p-1)}(x)$ are all solutions to the equation $f^{(p)}(x)$. Furthermore,
>
> - if $q > 1$ is a positive integer that divides $p$, then $f^{(p/q)}(x)$ is a solution to the equation $f^{(q)}(x) = x$, so that if $x$ has period $p$, $f^{(p/q)}(x)$ has period $q$
> - if $p$ is prime, then the set $\{x, f(x), \cdots, f^{(k)}(x), \cdots, f^{(p-1)}(x)\}$ are *distinct* solutions to the equation $f^{(p)}(x)$, and therefore are periodic solutions of period $p$

To be able to say a little bit more about the periods of order $p$, consider the following general pattern. Write $x_{n+p} = \frac{f_p(x_n)}{g_p(x_n)}$ where $f_p$ and $g_p$ are the polynomials in $x_n$ we obtain by iterating the above idea $p$ times instead of $2$ times. We saw that
$$
\deg f_1 = 2, \quad \deg g_1 = 1, \quad \deg f_2 = 4, \quad \deg g_2 = 3.
$$
Let us prove by induction on $n$ that $\deg f_p = 2^p$ and $\deg g_p = 2^p-1$. The base case is proved already, and
$$
\frac{f_{p+1}(x_n)}{g_{p+1}(x_n)} = \frac{f_p(x_n)}{g_p(x_n)} - \frac{g_p(x_n)}{f_p(x_n)} = \frac{f_p(x_n)^2 - g_p(x_n)^2}{f_p(x_n)g_p(x_n)}. 
$$
Since $\deg g_p < \deg f_p$ by induction, no cancellation occurs in the numerator, so $\deg f_{p+1} = 2 \deg f_p = 2^{p+1}$. Then $\deg g_{p+1} = \deg f_p + \deg g_p = 2^p + 2^p - 1 = 2^{p+1}-1$.

This proves our induction hypothesis, so we can deduce the following result:

> Let $p > 1$ be a positive integer. There are at most $2^p - 2$ solutions to the equation $f^{(p)}(x) = x$.

The proof is simple; the solutions to that equation are solution to the polynomial equation $f^p(x) - xg_p(x) = 0$, and this polynomial has degree at most $2^p$.

We can slightly improve our result by noticing that there is some cancellation involved in that subtraction. By induction on $n$, one easily sees that the leading coefficients of $f_p$ and $g_p$ are both $1$, so the leading term of $f_p(x)$ and $xg_p(x)$ are the same.

We can also see by induction on $n$ that $f_p(x)$ is an even polynomial function and $g_p(x)$ is an odd polynomial function, so $x g_p(x)$ is even. Even polynomial functions can be written as polynomials in $x^2$, meaning that the terms of odd degree of $f_p(x)$ and $xg_p(x)$ are all zero. This brings our upper bound down on the number of solutions to $2^p-2$.

I believe this upper bound is sharp (but this is conjectural) since using *sympy*, I computed
$$
f_3(x) = x^8 - 7x^6 + 13x^4 - 7x^2 + 1, \quad xg_3(x) = x^8 - 4x^6 + 4x^4 - x^2 
$$
and so we see that there is no cancellation. I repeated the reasoning computationally and it seems to hold for $p \le 15$, where the polynomial has degree $2^p-2$.

Note that nothing says the polynomial doesn't have double roots, so we can't claim that there are always exactly $2^p-2$ solutions. Some of them might be repeated roots of that polynomial.

If I find more interesting results, I'll add to this answer.

EDIT: Adding here my sympy code to generate the polynomials $f_p$ and $g_p$.

```
from sympy.abc import x
def recurrence_relation():
    f = x
    g = 1
    while True:
            yield (f,g)
            f,g = f**2 - g**2, f*g

def first_n_terms(n):
    for (f,g), i in zip(recurrence_relation(), range(n)):
            if i <= 1:
                    continue
            print(f"Polynomial f_p: {f}")
            print(f"Polynomial xg_p: {x*g}")
            print(f"Degree of f_p - xg_p: {poly(f-x*g, x).degree()}")
```

I hope this tells you roughly how to operate with sympy for your own experiments.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you give me details on how you calculated $f_p(x)$ and $xg_p(x)$ with sympy? That's exactly what I need to solve my problem.

Comment: @Sephka : I added my code in the answer. Why exactly did you want them? I understand they're interesting, but I wasn't able to prove anything with those computations, just elaborate on my conjecture.

Comment: I'm looking for the roots of $f^{p}(x)=x$ so I can use your code do calculate the polynomials. I tried to do it all numerically but for $p>6$ it's not viable because there are to many roots. I wasn't sure how to calculate the polynomials out of the relation. So thanks for your help. I hope that solves my problem!

Comment: Okay I used your code to tackle my problem but I think I need another approach. For p>9 the root finding just takes too long because the degree of the polynomial is already over $500$. Since I want to look at the roots for p>20 I'll have to think of another way.
I'll mark your answer as accepted since it helped me to advance with this problem. Thank's again!

Comment: @Sephka: What I checked algorithmically is the degree of the polynomial, which I could check in a reasonable amount of time (few seconds) for $p <= 15$. But computing the roots of a polynomial of degree $2^n$ takes a lot of time. This is definitely superlinear in the degree if not more, so for a polynomial of degree $2^n$, we're talking super-exponential time, which is not cool. If you want we can discuss the original problem so you don't have to compute those roots! There's too many of them anyway for high degree ($2^10$ roots? Do you really wanna look at those?)!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that my approach doesn't work because the degree is too large. I will edit my post to add more information about the original problem!

Comment: @Sephka: If you have another follow-up question that is fundamentally different in flavor from this one, feel free to make a new question and link it to this one to avoid making my answer obsolete.

Comment: I moved the questions to a new topic and linked it in my original post!