# Finding values for which sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n-1/x_n$ is periodic

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, project-euler

I'm looking at the sequence 
$x_{n+1}=x_n-1/x_n$ 
and want to find starting values $x_0$ for which the sequence is periodic. I want to calculate all values for which the sequence is periodic with a period $p<P$. 
The problem can be rewritten as:
$f(x)=x-1/x$ 
and $f^p$ is the function applied $p$-times.

To calculate the values for which the sequence is periodic I tried to find the $x_0$ for which $f^{p}(x_0)=x_0$ by looking at the roots of $f^{p}(x_0)-x_0$.
Since the degree of the polynomial is ~$2^p$ (look [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3977381/871291)) this approach is not viable for $p>10$.

*More Background info:* 
I'm interested in finding the range of the periodic sequences so for a given cycle 
$S={x_0,...,x_n}$ 
where $f(x_n)=x_0$ 
I want to calculate the range:
$r=max(S)-min(S)$

So any ideas or hints on how to calculate the range (directly) or how to get the values for which the sequence is periodic will be greatly appreciated.

[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3977381/871291)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici this was my original question. This is a follow up because the scope is a bit different

Comment: Sorry for that !

Comment: Warning: this is Problem 729 of Project Euler. Their policy concerning public discussions of the problems is known, and generally accepted at MSE. Please, don't support cheating!

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know about that. I don't want a full solution i just want an idea how to approach that mathematical problem. I can close this question if necessary